# Delete empty cells (shift up)

Tags: excel, vba

whats wrong with my code below? I want to delete empty cells and shift up the rest of data (around 10 columns)

But I am getting the error: application defined or object defined error.

```
Sub delete_empty_cells()

    Sheets("Incidents_data").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confine your cell deletion to the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx).

```
With Worksheets("Incidents_data")
    .UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With
```